# List of Dictionaries as a value for key of list of dictionary

Tags: python

I have following list of dictionaries.

```
p = [ {"Id": "47","Name": "l","Cate": "GD31"},
     {"Id": "58","Name": "k","Cate": "GD33"},
    {"Id": "40","Name": "j","Cate": "GD35"},
    {"Id": "15","Name": "i","Cate": "GD37"},
    {"Id": "39","Name": "h","Cate": "GD39"},
    {"Id": "75","Name": "g","Cate": "LD31"},
    {"Id": "12","Name": "f","Cate": "LD33"},
    {"Id": "92","Name": "e","Cate": "LD35"},
    {"Id": "42","Name": "d","Cate": "LD37"},
    {"Id": "11","Name": "c","Cate": "LD39"},
    {"Id": "51","Name": "b","Cate": "SWW"},
    {"Id": "13","Name": "a","Cate": "SMM"} ]
```

In the above dictionary, I want to store the particular dictionary to some variable based on the "Cate" value equal to GD31 or LD31. What I have tried is:

```
D31 = [{d["Cate"]: [{"Id": d["Id"], "Name_" + d["Cate"][0]: 
d["Name"]}] for d in p if "D31" in d["Cate"]}]
```

and I have a output:

```
    [{'GD31': [{'Id': '47', 'Name_G': 'l'}], 'LD31': [{'Id': '75', 'Name_L': 'g'}]}]
```

Explanation:

If D31 is found, Select that particular Dictionary Alone from the list of dictionaries. In that particular Dictionary Take "Id" and "Name". Hence, GD31 and LD31 is a key and "Id, Name" are values. And If D31 is found, update "Name" as "Name_G" for GD31 and "Name_L" for LD31. ***And this is for all values D33, D35, D37 and D39.

Now What I need is:

In the result, I need to change "boy" instead of "GD13" and "Girl" instead of "LD31" (It is applicable for all values D33,D35,D37.D39) ["boy" for "Cate" starts with "G" and "girl" for "Cate" starts with "L"] like this:

```
    [{'boy': [{'Id': '47', 'Name_G': 'l'}], 'girl': [{'Id': '75', 'Name_L': 'g'}]}]
```

I hope you all understand this. Any ideas?please...

Comment: I think I get what you're asking, but please [edit] to add the full expected output. See [mre] for comparison. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also did you swap `d` with `p` by accident?

Comment: Edited. Please check. @wjandrea

Comment: `KeyError: 'Category'`. Please read [mre].

Comment: Edited. Sorry I have just confuesd. @wjandrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EmeraldCaro, will this work or do you need me to modify it to your new table:

```
def getgates(hm): 
  s={} 
  for item in p:  
     if hm in item['Cate']:  
      if item['Cate'][0] == 'G':
       s['boy'] = [{"Id": item['Id'], "Name_" + item['Cate'][0]: item['Code']}] 
      elif item['Cate'][0] == 'L':
       s['girl'] = [{"Id": item['Id'], "Name_" + item['Cate'][0]: item['Code']}] 
  return s 


print(getgates('D31'))
{'boy': [{'Id': '47', 'Name_G': 'l'}], 'girl': [{'Id': '75', 'Name_L': 'g'}]}

print(getgates('D39'))
{'boy': [{'Id': '39', 'Name_G': 'h'}], 'girl': [{'Id': '11', 'Name_L': 'c'}]}
```